# I cant supply my database with my API using dota2 API

Tags: django, postgresql, api, graphql

When i run insert_heroes.py file I get this image https://prnt.sc/qlk2bp

insert_heroes.py

```
import requests
import json

if __name__ == '__main__':
    r = requests.get("https://api.opendota.com/api/heroes")
    all_heroes_info = json.loads(r.content.decode('UTF-8'))

    for hero_info in all_heroes_info:
        name = hero_info['localized_name']
        hero_type = hero_info['primary_attr']

        mutation_create_hero = '''
                  mutation ($name: String!, $heroType: String!) {
                      createHero(name: $name, heroType: $heroType) {
                          name
                      }
                  }
              '''

        fill_db = mutation_create_hero, variable_values = {'name': name, 'heroType': hero_type}
        print(fill_db)
```

I created variable called fill_db to be equal to mutation that will create all new heroes from dota 2 API and then i just printed fill_db.
I got all heroes from that get request but problem is that i dont know now how to push all that into my postgreSQL database. I dont have a clue how to do it.

I need some kind of command that will put this params and mutation in square brackets as parameters somethig like client.execute()

Can you help me guys?

Comment: Your provided link does not open any image ! Please fix it

Comment: it opens image, here is again - > https://prnt.sc/qlqeji